# Add a class to specific elements with pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, svg

I am evaluating an Svg coloring image. A function evaluates the fill colors set by the user, against a correct answers list, by looping through them with `querySelectorAll` method and converted (to compare their values) to arrays. Only the paths with the class `setColor` can be colored.

**Question:** How can I add the class `wrongColor` ONLY to the path elements that have the wrong fill color?

```
<!--Hypothetical SVG that must be colored correctly.-->
    <svg width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path id="aSVG" class="setColor" d="M10 10 C 20 20, 40 20, 50 10" stroke="black" fill="green" />
        <path id="bSVG" class="setColor" d="M70 10 C 70 20, 120 20, 120 10" stroke="black" fill="red" />
        <path d="M130 10 C 120 20, 180 20, 170 10" stroke="black" fill="white" />
        <path id="cSVG" class="setColor" d="M10 60 C 20 80, 40 80, 50 60" stroke="black" fill="lightblue" />
        <path id="dSVG" class="setColor" d="M70 60 C 70 80, 110 80, 110 60" stroke="black" fill="lightblue" />
        <path d="M130 60 C 120 80, 180 80, 170 60" stroke="black" fill="white" />
        <path id="eSVG" class="setColor" d="M10 110 C 20 140, 40 140, 50 110" stroke="black" fill="lightblue" />
        <path id="fSVG" class="setColor" d="M70 110 C 70 140, 110 140, 110 110" stroke="black" fill="lightblue" />
        <path d="M130 110 C 120 140, 180 140, 170 110" stroke="black" fill="white" />
    </svg>


    <!--Correct answers list. Not visible in user-->
    <ol class="answersList">
        <li class="t1">red</li>
        <li class="t1">green</li>
        <li class="t1">lightblue</li>
        <li class="t1">lightblue</li>
        <li class="t1">lightblue</li>
        <li class="t1">lightblue</li>
    </ol>
```

Below is a functional example in order to clarify the functionality of the game.

**@Amethystx87** Your code adds class `wrongColor` to **all** the paths with the class `setColor`. You can see it below in the code Snippet. The `map` property will create error "document.querySelectorAll(...).map is not a function" because `querySelectorAll` returns a `Node List` (array like) so you have to convert the `Node List` to array and then array methods can be used.

I had the same problem too and solved it as in the JavaScript code below with the comments "check users answers","check correct answers list". In the comment "Amethystx87 solution" is the way I made your code to work but not completely there yet.

**@DacreDenny** I couldn't utilize your solution maybe  my fault. I hope the code snippet below can give you a clear view of the problem. You will see in the snippet that the  wrong answers (I made the mistake on purpose) are the first two (green,red) but the correct (red, green) are as appeared in the answer list.

```js
/*~~~~~~~~check button~~~~~~~~~~~*/

document.querySelector(".check").addEventListener('click', checkSvgAnswers);

function checkSvgAnswers() {


  /*~~~check users answers~~~*/

  var selectedFillColor = document.querySelectorAll(".setColor");
  var selectedFillColorArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < selectedFillColor.length; i++) {
    var selectedColors = selectedFillColor[i].getAttribute('fill').toUpperCase();
    selectedFillColorArray.push(selectedColors);
  }

  console.log(selectedFillColorArray);

  /*~~~check correct answers list~~~~~~~~~~~*/

  var correctAnswers = document.querySelectorAll("li.t1");
  var correctAnswersArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < correctAnswers.length; i++) {
    var answerList = correctAnswers[i].innerText.toUpperCase();
    correctAnswersArray.push(answerList);
  }

  console.log(correctAnswersArray);

  /*~~~~compare answers helper function~~~~~~~~~~*/
  var isEqual = function(value, other) {

    // Get the value type
    var type = Object.prototype.toString.call(value);

    // If the two objects are not the same type, return false
    if (type !== Object.prototype.toString.call(other)) {
      return false;
    }

    // If items are not an object or array, return false
    if (['[object Array]', '[object Object]'].indexOf(type) < 0) {
      return false;
    }
    // Compare the length of the length of the two items
    var valueLen = type === '[object Array]' ? value.length : Object.keys(value).length;
    var otherLen = type === '[object Array]' ? other.length : Object.keys(other).length;
    if (valueLen !== otherLen) {
      return false;
    }
    // Compare two items
    var compare = function(item1, item2) {

      // Get the object type
      var itemType = Object.prototype.toString.call(item1);

      // If an object or array, compare recursively
      if (['[object Array]', '[object Object]'].indexOf(itemType) >= 0) {
        if (!isEqual(item1, item2)) {
          return false;
        }
      }

      // Otherwise, do a simple comparison
      else {

        // If the two items are not the same type, return false
        if (itemType !== Object.prototype.toString.call(item2)) {
          return false;
        }
        // Else if it's a function, convert to a string and compare
        // Otherwise, just compare
        if (itemType === '[object Function]') {

          if (item1.toString() !== item2.toString()) {

            return false;
          }
        } else if (item1 !== item2) {

          return false;
        }

      }
    };
    // Compare properties
    if (type === '[object Array]') {
      for (var i = 0; i < valueLen; i++) {
        if (compare(value[i], other[i]) === false) {

          return false;
        }
      }
    } else {
      for (var key in value) {
        if (value.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          if (compare(value[key], other[key]) === false) {

            return false;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    // If nothing failed, return true
    return true;

  };

  /*~~~~~~~~compare colors~~~~~~~~~~~*/
  if (isEqual(selectedFillColorArray, correctAnswersArray)) {
    document.querySelector(".coloringResult").innerHTML = "<span style='color:#00B119;'>&#x2714;</span>";
  } else if (!isEqual(selectedFillColorArray, correctAnswersArray)) {
    document.querySelector(".coloringResult").innerHTML = "<span style='color:#D40D0D;'>&#10007;</span>";
  }
  console.log(isEqual(selectedFillColorArray, correctAnswersArray));

  /*~~~~~~~~Amethystx87 solution*/
  document.querySelectorAll('.setColor').forEach((element) => {
    if (!correctAnswersArray.includes(element.fill)) {
      element.classList.add('wrongColor');
    }
  });
};
```

```html
<!--Hypothetical color palette. User can drag and drop colors ONLY to svg paths with the class="setColor" to change the default "fill" color values-->
<div class="colorPalette">
  <p>green</p>
  <p>red</p>
  <p>lightblue</p>
</div>

<!--Hypothetical SVG that must be colored correctly.-->
<svg width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

        <path id="aSVG" class="setColor" d="M10 10 C 20 20, 40 20, 50 10" stroke="black" fill="green" />
        <path id="bSVG" class="setColor" d="M70 10 C 70 20, 120 20, 120 10" stroke="black" fill="red" />
        <path d="M130 10 C 120 20, 180 20, 170 10" stroke="black" fill="white" />
        <path id="cSVG" class="setColor" d="M10 60 C 20 80, 40 80, 50 60" stroke="black" fill="lightblue" />
        <path id="dSVG" class="setColor" d="M70 60 C 70 80, 110 80, 110 60" stroke="black" fill="lightblue" />
        <path d="M130 60 C 120 80, 180 80, 170 60" stroke="black" fill="white" />
        <path id="eSVG" class="setColor" d="M10 110 C 20 140, 40 140, 50 110" stroke="black" fill="lightblue" />
        <path id="fSVG" class="setColor" d="M70 110 C 70 140, 110 140, 110 110" stroke="black" fill="lightblue" />
        <path d="M130 110 C 120 140, 180 140, 170 110" stroke="black" fill="white" />

    </svg>

<!--Appears on check button click showing tick for correct, x for wrong.-->
<p class="coloringResult">&nbsp;</p>

<!--control buttons-->
<!--Check button: compares the users colors placed on the svg, with the correct colors from the answers list. Score container appears and shows user score-->
<button class='check' type='button'>Check</button>

<!--Try again button: keep the correct answers, the wrong answers return to the original "fill" color and the score is changed keeping only the correct colors score-->
<button class='try-again' type='button'>Try again</button>

<!--Reset button: reset exersice to original state. All svg paths to default "fill" color. Score resets to 0 and disappears from screen -->
<button class='clear-answers' type='button'>Reset</button>

<!--Correct answers list. Not visible in user-->
<ol class="answersList">
  <li class="t1">red</li>
  <li class="t1">green</li>
  <li class="t1">lightblue</li>
  <li class="t1">lightblue</li>
  <li class="t1">lightblue</li>
  <li class="t1">lightblue</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: John, how do the right answers map to the elements? If it is a certain color per element have you considered having a custom data attribute data-correct-color="red" for example.

Comment: @Paul Thomas Yes, it is a certain color per one or two elements. The colors are set to the svg paths, by the user with drag and drop from a color palette with the available colors, if I understand your question correctly. The _data attribute_ isn't  appropriate because I have a UI where the correct answers and color palette, can be edited even by someone who doesn't know programming i.e. a teacher. An answer list is more  accessible. Imagine it as an education tool.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
// Get all the correct colors and map them to an array
const correctColors = document.querySelectorAll('.t1')
  .map(element => return element.textContent);
// Loop through all with class setColor and add wrongColor to the element's classList
document.querySelectorAll('.setColor').forEach((element) => {
    if (!correctColors.includes(element.fill)) {
        element.classList.add('wrongColor');
    }
});
```

Comment: I will test it! I made a small correction  added {...} to the 3rd line because an error occured "SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'return'" I use Visual Studio and run it on Firefox. It is like this: `.map(element => {return element.textContent}
            });`

Comment: I have created a code snippet with your solution partially working. please check.

Answer (score 0):

You can query SVG elements, and update the classlist of SVG element in the same way that you would any other element in the DOM.

So for instance, you can query all SVG elements with a `fill` attribute value of a "wrong fill color" of `white` by doing this:

```
const wrongFillColor = "white";

document.querySelectorAll(`svg [fill="${wrongFillColor}"]`)
```

You can then iterate the resulting node set, and add classes to matching elements like so:

```js
const wrongFillColor = "white";

document.querySelectorAll(`svg [fill="${wrongFillColor}"]`).forEach(function(element) {
  element.classList.add("wrongColor")
})
```

```css
.wrongColor {
  fill: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!--Hypothetical SVG that must be colored correctly.-->
<svg width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path id="aSVG" class="setColor" d="M10 10 C 20 20, 40 20, 50 10" stroke="black" fill="green" />
        <path id="bSVG" class="setColor" d="M70 10 C 70 20, 120 20, 120 10" stroke="black" fill="red" />
        <path d="M130 10 C 120 20, 180 20, 170 10" stroke="black" fill="white" />
        <path id="cSVG" class="setColor" d="M10 60 C 20 80, 40 80, 50 60" stroke="black" fill="lightblue" />
        <path id="dSVG" class="setColor" d="M70 60 C 70 80, 110 80, 110 60" stroke="black" fill="lightblue" />
        <path d="M130 60 C 120 80, 180 80, 170 60" stroke="black" fill="white" />
        <path id="eSVG" class="setColor" d="M10 110 C 20 140, 40 140, 50 110" stroke="black" fill="lightblue" />
        <path id="fSVG" class="setColor" d="M70 110 C 70 140, 110 140, 110 110" stroke="black" fill="lightblue" />
        <path d="M130 110 C 120 140, 180 140, 170 110" stroke="black" fill="white" />
    </svg>
```

Comment: The highlighted wrong answers is a very nice addition!

Comment: @JohnJD thanks - did this answer your question? or did I misunderstand?

Comment: The wrong color can be anything. Imagine that the fill colors are set to the svg paths, by the user with drag and drop from a color palette with the available colors. But you gave me an idea. I will try it first, since the real svg game is more complex and I will tell you!

Comment: @JohnJD yes that's correct, the wrong color can be anything. The idea with `const wrongFillColor = "white";` is that once you have the wrong fill color (ie as picked by the user), you can then use the technique shown in this answer to apply your CSS class to shapes in your SVG with that fill color

Comment: OK! Testing continues!

Comment: I have created a code snippet to clarify the game functionality. Please check.